# Fetching column values from html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to get cell values inside these columns, but I'm getting only the headers of these columns in html table

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', {'class', 'annotation'})
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    if len(cells) == 21:
        gene_id = cells[4].text
        gene_aspect = cells[6].text
        print(gene_id, gene_aspect)
```

And I am getting this output

```
GO Identifier



Aspect
```

Although, I want the values present inside these two columns.

Comment: Can you paste the (relevant parts of the) `response`?

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'annotation'})
```

or

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='annotation')
```

The problem with your code is that

```
{'class', 'annotation'}
```

is a set, while BeautifulSoup expects a dict.